# What are the Keyboard Shortcuts for PDF Arranger?

Tags: pdf

Where can I find the keyboard shortcuts and configuration file for PDF Arranger?

Answer (score 0):

| Shortcuts |  |
| --- | --- |
| F10 | show main menu |
|  |  |
| ***Edit*** |  |
| Delete | delete |
| Ctrl + Z | undo |
| Ctrl + Y | redo |
| Ctrl + X | cut |
| Ctrl + C | copy |
| Ctrl + V | paste after |
| Ctrl + Shift + V | paste before |
| Ctrl + A | select all |
| Ctrl + Shift + A | de-select all |
|  |  |
| ***View*** |  |
| Ctrl + Right | rotate(90) |
| Ctrl + Left | rotate(-90) |
| Ctrl + + | zoom-in |
| Ctrl + - | zoom-out |
| F | zoom-fit |
| F11 | fullscreen |
|  |  |
| ***File*** |  |
| C | page-format |
| Ctrl + S | save |
| Ctrl + Shift + S | save-as |
| Ctrl + E | export selecting to single file |
| Ctrl + Shift + E | export all pages to individual files |
| Ctrl + P | print |
| Ctrl + W | close |
| Ctrl + Q | quit |
| Ctrl + N | new |
| Ctrl + O | open |
| Ctrl + I | import |

NOTE: The keyboard shortcuts for [PDF Arranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger) are located in `pdfarranger/pdfarranger/config.py`